# Traffic Light Indicator Filter

Tags: sharepoint-list, sharepoint-list-filter

I already created a traffic light indicator column for a SharePoint list. When I clicked on the column to filter, the options shown as the HTML code. My question here is how do I have the filter options on this column as the same as the indicator instead of HTML code. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can use JS link to achieve the traffic light indicator and filter the view at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I probably didn't explain well. I already achieved the traffic light indicator. So when I go to the traffic light column on the list and try to filter by like pick one filter selection (green, yellow, etc) like (Status column - in progress, approve etc.), it only shown the HTML code instead of green, yellow, etc. Can I format the filter selection screen/area? If yes, how would I do so and where can I find resource to do this. Thank you very much for the help.